# Avoid calling effect inside component when conditionally rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, react-hooks

I've got the following component:

```
const Component = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Component useEffect')
  }, [])

  return <Text>element</Text>
}
```

When I conditionally render the component above, the side effect gets called every time the component is re-attached:

```
{someCondition && <Component />}
```

Is there a way to avoid this by memoizing the rendered element somehow? Is this due to the nature of hooks being sensitive to ordering...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either perform the effect inside your parent component or move the `conditional render` logic inside child component

```
const Parent = () =>{
    return <Child condition={false} />
}

const Child = ({ condition }) =>{
    useEffect(() =>{},[])

    return condition ? <span /> : null 
}
```

Comment: I get that hooks can't be called conditionally, `Component` is being rendered conditionally here. Is this the same?

Comment: If I understood right you want to execute the effect only once, regardless of how many times it gets mounted and unmounted right? Well if the effect is defined inside your component you can't achieve this behavior. Everytime the component gets mounted again the effect will run.

Comment: That's correct. If I understand right, we need to be aware of if a child component using hooks or not when dealing with conditional mounting?

Comment: No. Perhaps I'm not explaining right. I removed the comment about conditionally call a hook.

Comment: My point is: Hooks always run at least one time uppon mounting. If the component is mounted multiple times the effect will run multiple times

Comment: Ok I think I get it now. The solution could be to not using hooks in this particular case? (I want the component not to call the side effect every time it gets mounted.)

Comment: Either keep the component always mounted (like in the answer) or move the side effect to the parent(if possible)

Comment: After refreshing my knowledge about hooks (`It serves the same purpose as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount in React classes, but unified into a single API.`) I think there is a third solution: using traditional class component in this case since that has `constructor`.

Comment: a `constructor` which will always gets called everytime you mount and a mount the class component

Comment: Sadly =(. It's a very unusual use case. If you post a more concise example perhaps we can find a workaround

Comment: In this particular case I'm facing with, a component that self manages API calls using hooks is passed to React Natives `FlatList` `ListHeaderComponent`. The problem comes in when the `FlatList` gets re-mounted: all child components get remounted resulting new calls to the API. Solution A: instead of unmounting the list do hide/show. Solution B: Use API caching. Solution C: manage API calls centralised and provide results to components. Have you got any better idea?